# Decorator for allure.step

Tags: python, python-decorators, allure

I want to write decorator for allure.step to add returned value to allure step.

The first way:

```
import allure

def allure_step(step):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
            result = step(*args, **kwargs)
            with allure.step("Return: {}".format(result)):
                pass
            return result
        result = allure.step(step.__name__)(wrap_func)(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrap


@allure_step
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Log:

[image]

Return value is added, but arguments are combined into one tuple. I can fix it by adding one more internal step:

```
import allure

def allure_step(step):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        with allure.step(step.__name__):
            result = allure.step("internal step")(step)(*args, **kwargs)
            with allure.step("Return: {}".format(result)):
                pass
        return result
    return wrap

@allure_step
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Log:

[image]

But I don't like this solution because I need to do one more click when check logs :)

Is it possible to write decorator with correct arguments and without additional internal step? or any other way to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I know that a lot of time has passed, but you can do this:

```
def allure_step(step):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrap_func(**kwargs):
            result = step(**kwargs)
            with allure.step("Результат: {}".format(result)):
                pass
            return result
        keys = step.__code__.co_varnames
        params = {}
        for arg, key in zip(args, keys):
            params[key] = arg
        for i in kwargs:
            params[i] = kwargs[i]
        result = allure.step(step.__name__)(wrap_func)(**params)
        return result
    return wrap
```

the point is to pass a dictionary and not args